# Why does my flash video get stuck? (not lag?)

Tags: video, flash, youtube

After moving to Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition, I've noticed a strange problem that manifests itself most obviously with streaming videos like youtube and hulu.  The video will load and begin playing fine and eventually stop, as though it is buffering.  However, it usually happens between 40 and 60 seconds into the clip.  The loading indication however shows that it actually isn't buffering anymore of the data, and will just sit there.  If I force the clip forward (e.g. click to start the movie somewhere ahead of the stall point) the clip will usually reload  quickly and begin playing as expected.

Because of the quick load times, and the consistent stop of video, I don't think the problem is related to hardware performance or network throughput.  Also, I have none of these problems in 10.04.  Rebooting into 10.04 makes the problem disappear.

However, one more clue, I also have noticed a higher occurrence of web pages that simply "stop loading" - say, 1/10 clicks while browsing I have to hit "reload" to get the page to load because the page timed out part of the way through. This seems strangely related to the video problem, though is a lot less infuriating.

Help! Where do I begin to look with a problem like this?

Comment: It works fine for me, but I compiled my own video codecs and I am using standard not netbook

Comment: How much space is left on your hard disk?

Comment: I have about 2.8GB free on my main partition.  The others have more..

Comment: Sorry, wrong guess then. :-) I presume your system is fully up-to-date and you've restarted your machine after the last update?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the ~/.macromedia folder and restart the browser. If you play flash games online, most likely you will lose your scores. So back it up if you need them.

Comment: sorry, that didn't help.  After paying closer attention, it seems like I see more webpages timeout than usual as well.  I'm beginning to think it's unrelated to flash and more to do with general networking..

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem since a couple of days ago. It happens on YouTube and TerraTV, while it doesn't happen on Globo Videos. I think the problem is a combination of factors, like the type of player the site has, flash version and network. I also noticed that some YouTube videos buffer a lot faster than others. I have Ubuntu 10.04 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link. This may solve your problem.

http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/11/fix-youtube-video-freeze-while-in-full.html

Comment: Sorry, the problem described there is unrelated - it has to do with video getting stuck when moving to full screen.  I tried their workaround anyway with no luck. :(